# Error : No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access

I want to insert all DataGridView rows to Database.
I faced this error

> No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < TimesDgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into TimesTBL(PeriodName,TimeFrom,TimeTo,Duration) values (@PeriodName,@TimeFrom,@TimeTo,@Duration)", con);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PeriodName", TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeFrom", TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString("hh:mm"));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeTo", TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString("hh:mm"));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Duration", TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      cmd = null;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsbOu.jpg)

Comment: My problem is solved by using `Convert.ToDateTime`
`Convert.ToDateTime(TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString("hh:mm")`

Comment: The problem is that the `DataGridViewCell.Value` property is typed as an `object` (think about it, a cell can hold anything, it needs to be of type `object`) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCell_Value. In your specific case, that object refers to a DateTime, but the property type is object. You don't have to _Convert_ it, you can simply cast it

Comment: How can I cast it?

Comment: `((DateTime)(TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value)).ToString("Format")`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that `TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value` is a `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`. But it's not. Not as far as your compiler is concerned.

Maybe you meant to Parse or Cast it into one?

Comment: (TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value) contain this value (11/27/2021 1:20 AM) but I want insert to My table only Time (1:20).

Comment: Well, as I said, you need to either `Parse` or cast it into a `DateTime` first. Since we have no idea what type `TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value` is, that is as much help as anybody can give you. Maybe you can post a [MCVE]?